# Dynamic Resolution Fix to NuxtJS Download Page

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, resolution

So I'm building a static site using Nuxt.js that acts as a catalog. I built the download page a while back, but the issue I'm running into is that the resolution for each section does not change or scale according to screen resolutions (it also looks horrendous on mobile devices for this reason)--either content blocks are clashing with one another or they are too far apart. I tried changing the display to block instead of flex, but that did not seem to work. Also tried putting the margins to auto, but that also didn't work. I wonder if it has to do with the fact that all blocks are in their own containers or if I'm simply overlooking something. Attached here is the template for the page--this template needs to have a dynamic resolution fix before I can start adding items to the catalog.

```
<template>
    <div class="download-page">
      <div class="thumbnail-container">
        <img src="/assets/mod_prevs/[mod_prev_here].webp" class="stained-glass" alt="Software Thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="title-container">
        <p class="stained-glass">TITLE PLACEHOLDER</p>
      </div>
      <div class="author-container">
        <div class="stained-glass">
          <div class="author-names">
            <p>Author(s): PLACEHOLDER</p>
          </div>
          <div class="contributors">
            <p>Contributor(s): PLACEHOLDER</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p class="stained-glass">DESCRIPTION PLACEHOLDER</p>
      </div>
      <h2 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 2em;">DOWNLOAD HERE!</h2>
      <div class="download-links">
        <div class="stained-glass">
          <h3>Versions</h3>
          <hr>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="/assets/gui/dl.webp" alt="Download Icon" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin-right: 10px;">
              <a href="[link_here]" target="_blank">PLACEHOLDER - Download (#gb)</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    name: 'DownloadPage'
  }
  </script>
  
  <style scoped>
  .download-page {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  }
  
  .thumbnail-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(3deg);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  
  .thumbnail-container img {
    width: 720px;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .title-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 5em;
    margin-right: 80px;
    animation: pulse 8s linear infinite;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(3deg);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  
  .author-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 370px;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-right: 80px;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(3deg);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 800px;
  }
  
  .author-names {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .contributors {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 0.45em;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .description {
    margin-top: 550px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1600px;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(3deg);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
  
  .download-links {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 2em;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 15px;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(3deg);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 60%;
  }
  
  .download-links ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  
  .download-links ul li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .stained-glass {
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    animation: pulse 8s linear infinite;
  }
  
  .stained-glass img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  @keyframes pulse {
    0% {
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }
    20% {
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
     40% {
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.8);
    }
    60% {
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 192, 203, 0.8);
    }
    80% {
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(148, 0, 211, 0.8);
    }
    100% {
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }
  }
  </style>
```

I'm happy to answer any questions or clarify anything. Any help is appreciated.